# Allow links to reference the headers in answers (or questions)

Tags: feature-request, markdown

### Problem

There are many answers on Stack Overflow that consist of hundreds or thousands of line of explanation, documentation, and code, and while the people who post those answers usually use headings and segment their content accordingly, but since there is no way to reference a part of your answer (rather than the whole answer itself), you may have to scroll quite a bit before finding the section you are actually interested in.

The person that posts the answer has devoted a certain amount of their time, so the first time you are going through the answer you should try to read and comprehend most of it. But if you have favorited or bookmarked the answer since it solves a frequent problem and you need a part that isn't very close to the top, you will have to scroll every time you visit the question.

### Proposed solution

If you were able to give an id to headers (or have Stack Overflow generate one for you), you would then be able to add that to a link using `#id` at the of the link.

Example:

```
[Find Header 1 here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388438/allow-links-to-reference-the-headers-in-answers-or-questions#header-1)
<span id="header-1">Header 1</span>
-----------------------------------
```

Which would look like:

[Find Header 1 here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388438/allow-links-to-reference-the-headers-in-answers-or-questions#id)

### Header 1

Comment: To summarise - allow building a table of content in posts. Correct? Although I realise it's *more* than just a ToC - you'd also be able to say "An example **here**" and link to another part of the post.

Comment: @VLAZ Pretty much, as well as being able to store the link with the `#` in your bookmarks

Comment: Last time I checked the Common Mark specs didn't have consensus on how anchors should be implemented. Until that time, don't expect progress on this feature within the normal [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) time frame.,

Comment: One of the many dupes on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts